# how to play youtube videos in video view

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview

i am developing to play youtube videos in videoview, i am getting error like **"Can't play this video"**. i used this code to play youtube videos in video view

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private VideoView videoView;
     private MediaController mController;
     private Uri uriYouTube;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        mController = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mController);
        videoView.requestFocus();


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
             int loc = savedInstanceState.getInt("Loc");
             Log.i("Loaction: ", loc + "");
             uriYouTube = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("url"));
             videoView.setVideoURI(uriYouTube);
             videoView.seekTo(loc);


             videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
             @Override
             public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
             Log.v("onPrepared", "ok");
             mp.start();
             }
             });
             } else {
             RTSPUrlTask truitonTask = new RTSPUrlTask();
             truitonTask.execute("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zNSgSzhBfM");
             }

             }

             void startPlaying(String url) {
             uriYouTube = Uri.parse(url);
             videoView.setVideoURI(uriYouTube);
             videoView.start();
             }

             @Override
             protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
             super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
             outState.putInt("Loc", videoView.getCurrentPosition());
             outState.putString("url", uriYouTube.toString());
             }

            /* @Override
             public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
             getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.video_view, menu);
             return true;
             }*/

             private class RTSPUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
             @Override
             protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
             String response = getRTSPVideoUrl(urls[0]);
             return response;
             }

             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             startPlaying(result);
             }

             public String getRTSPVideoUrl(String urlYoutube) {
             try {
             String gdy = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
             DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
             .newDocumentBuilder();
             String id = extractYoutubeId(urlYoutube);
             URL url = new URL(gdy + id);
             HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
             .openConnection();
             Document doc = dBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
             Element el = doc.getDocumentElement();
             NodeList list = el.getElementsByTagName("media:content");
             String cursor = urlYoutube;
             for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
             Node node = list.item(i);
             if (node != null) {
             NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
             HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
             for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++) {
             Attr att = (Attr) nodeMap.item(j);
             maps.put(att.getName(), att.getValue());
             }
             if (maps.containsKey("yt:format")) {
             String f = maps.get("yt:format");
             if (maps.containsKey("url"))
             cursor = maps.get("url");
             if (f.equals("1"))
             return cursor;
             }
             }
             }
             return cursor;
             } catch (Exception ex) {
             return urlYoutube;
             }
             }

             public String extractYoutubeId(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
             String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
             String[] param = query.split("&");
             String id = null;
             for (String row : param) {
             String[] param1 = row.split("=");
             if (param1[0].equals("v")) {
             id = param1[1];
             }
             }
             return id;
             }
    }
```

this is my xml file, 
i am getting url error and also **couldn't open file on client side trying server side**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".VideoViewActivity"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please suggest me a way to load youtube videos in android video view.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

Please use the YouTube Android Player API https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: my requirement is to play in video view that is what i mentioned video view, could you help me to solve this issues

Comment: i have one link for you. Hope it will work http://www.truiton.com/2013/08/android-videoview-example-with-youtube-playback/

Comment: i am using your code but i am getting "can't play this video" i am using micromax device could you tell me what problem?

Comment: According to me this Can’t play this video notification comes in two cases: 1.Unsupported file format 2.Due to missing internet access permissions

Comment: i put internet permission in manifest and also i am using same video url as what given your tutorial, even though i am getting this error what can i do?

Comment: this is log cat exception : setDataSource: IOException! uri=rtsp://r1---sn-a5m7zu7z.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnzBeEsgVIz2xMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp, could you tell me what can i do for this?

Comment: Give me time, i need to see this at my end.

Comment: Hey dawood, I checked at my end.The link i provided is working absolutely fine.Video is playing at my end. I testing it as sample app which i tested on tablet. Please test it on some other device other than micromax. See what happens.

Comment: i tried in nexus tab also but same thing happen, i updated my code as per your tutorial, just check it, and tell me, if i did any wrong .

Comment: I have also used the same code what link have. Make sure your internet is working.

Comment: if we want to use youtube player instead of videoview, in that case our video is working if it has youtube app in our device.is there any possible to play videos by using youtube player without youtube app.

Comment: In that case, it would not be possible. As you are firing the intent to and it handle by youtube app that have a player and capable of playing it.

Comment: i tried to put rtsp url of any video and put it into browser. why the videos is not playing in browser this is sample rtsp url just check it tell me. rtsp://r8---sn-a5m7zu7l.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnOmq0W2-ZArRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp